# How to give custom colour for each date in angular bsDatepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap bsDatepicker in my angular application to show calendar.
I need to give different colour for some dates in the calendar. For eg;
[image]

Here i need to give blue background colour for 28 and 29, red for 30 and 31. I already search in web but i didn't find any way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched the documentation? https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#date-custom-classes

Comment: @penleychan thanks for ur comment, i got solution with ur link, pls see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I created a dateCustomClasses array by conditionally.

```
let dateCustomClasses = this.getDates(minDate, maxDate);

getDates = (startDate, endDate) => {
    var dates = [],
      currentDate = startDate,
      addDays = function (days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
      };
    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
      let className = "blue";
      if (myCondition) {
        className = "red";
      }
      dates.push({ date: currentDate, classes: [className] });
      currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
    }
    return dates;
  };

<input type="text" name="new_buyback_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date"
      [(ngModel)]="date" [bsConfig]="bsConfig" [minDate]="minDate"
      [maxDate]="maxDate" (bsValueChange)="onDateChange($event)"
      [dateCustomClasses]="dateCustomClasses" bsDatepicker required>
```